# htaccess, redirect with regex: Folder to variable

Tags: regex, .htaccess, variables, redirect, directory

I hope you can help me out with my little problem:

I have an URL like so:

```
www.blabla.com/images/q2uj89j2fq89hf943ghf74ßgq3789fg43/blue.jpg
```

Inside the "images" folder i have a PHP Skript that should get everything between the string "images/" and the following "/" as a GET variable. So something like this:

```
www.blabla/images/script.php?param=q2uj89j2fq89hf943ghf74ßgq3789fg43
```

**Currently I have the following htaccess file:**

```
Options +FollowSymlinks
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule  ^(.*)$ script.php?param=$1 [QSA,L]
```

But with this I am getting something like this:

```
www.blabla/images/script.php?param=q2uj89j2fq89hf943ghf74ßgq3789fg43/blue.jpg
```

and obviously I only want to get everything until the next /

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`.` allows for any character to match and `$` **explicitly** says you want to match all the way to the end of the string.

You can use a negated character class instead of the `.` and remove the `$`. The negated character class will match any character **except for** slashes (the `^` marks the character class negated):

```
RewriteRule  ^([^/]*) script.php?param=$1 [QSA,L]
```

Since regex repetition is greedy by default, this will take in as many characters as possible. That is everything until the next slash.

Comment: Thank you very much. Exactly what I wanted. Finally.. :)